# A more shorter way of writing $[X-d, X+d]$?

Tags: notation, confidence-interval

Confidence intervals are usually of the form $[X-d, X+d]$, where $X$ and $d$ are repeated twice. Is there a more compact way of writing this?

Comment: $$X\pm d$$ but this could be understood as $1-\sigma$ error bars without further qualifiers.

Comment: @A.S. that was my concern with that notation, as it could be ambiguous. Maybe $[X\pm d]$ instead?

Comment: That wouldn't be any clearer. Since you need to specificy the level of your CI interval anyway somewhere, $X\pm d$ should be clear in context. I think this form is customary for directly measurable variables and $[a,b]$ form for latent parameters.

Comment: I'd personally just go $[X,d]$ where I have made it clear prior that it refers to that interval.

Comment: Looked around. You should report $CI$'s in the standard: $ X=1, 95\% \text{ CI  } [0.11, 1.23]$ form.

Comment: Since the interval can be defined as the set of numbers $y$ for which $|X-y|\leq d$, it's the closed ball of center $X$ with radius $d$ (for the usual metric on the real line), which is generally noted $B[X,d]$. But it's not used very frequently in dimension $1$...

Comment: @Arnaud The center of parameter's confidence interval has no special significance and emphasizing it is unjustified/misleading.

Comment: "Is there a more compact way of writing this?" None that one can recommend.